# CS50 Week 3 Plurality not accepting correct printed candidates , still gives error

Tags: c, cs50

I've tested my code several times and it works perfectly fine.
I get the correct winners, I even get multiple winners without any issue.
But check50 still gives me the following results:

```
:) plurality.c exists
:) plurality compiles
:) vote returns true when given name of first candidate
:) vote returns true when given name of middle candidate
:) vote returns true when given name of last candidate
:) vote returns false when given name of invalid candidate
:) vote produces correct counts when all votes are zero
:) vote produces correct counts after some have already voted
:) vote leaves vote counts unchanged when voting for invalid candidate
:( print_winner identifies Alice as winner of election
    print_winner function did not print winner of election
:( print_winner identifies Bob as winner of election
    print_winner function did not print winner of election
:( print_winner identifies Charlie as winner of election
    print_winner function did not print winner of election
:( print_winner prints multiple winners in case of tie
    print_winner function did not print both winners of election
:( print_winner prints all names when all candidates are tied
    print_winner function did not print all three winners of election
```

my printing code:

```
// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    bool n = 0;
    for (int i = candidate_count; i > 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (candidates[j].votes == i)
            {
                printf("%s\n", candidates[j].name);
                n = true;
            }
        }
        if (n == true)
        {
           break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe the trailing space isn't tasted.

Comment: both cases with and without the space it doesn't work. i edited the code to remove the space

Comment: `if (candidates[j].votes == i)` Is there some relation between the number of possible votes for a candidate and the number of candidates? What happens if a candidate gets more votes than candidates are there?

Answer (score 0):

If there are 3 candidates and one gets 6 votes, your "count down and count up" will never find that winner...

```
int winner = 0;
for( int i = 1; i < ncandidates; i++ )
    if( candidates[ i ].votes > candidates[ winner ].votes )
        winner = i;

for( int i = 0; i < ncandidates; i++ )
    if( candidates[ i ].votes == candidates[ winner ].votes )
        printf( "Winner: %s\n", candidates[ i ].votes );
```

Now, your exercise is to distinguish "multiple winners" (ie: a tie)...

Comment: thank you for your help, i couldn't use your code as i should find a way to fix my own code to submit it for CS50, your answer helped me navigate my way through the solution

Comment: You're welcome. :-) An 'upvote' on this answer would boost my reputation tally :-) Cheers!

Comment: can't cast votes yet lol, will do once i get my 15 reputation points

Answer (score 0):

found the issue, although don't understand why
it's this line:

```
for (int i = candidate_count; i > 0; i--)
```

it should be

```
for (int i = MAX; i > 0; i--)
```

candidate_count + 1 didn't work as well, it should be MAX for some reason